# How to programmatically count how many items are in a JSON file

Tags: c#, json, rest, sharepoint, json.net

I am querying SharePoint for a list of all folders within a document library (using REST API). I need to know the amount of folders that were found and the amount of items within each folder.  (These numbers will change regularly as the client adds/removes folders.)

I've currently passed the string returned from the query into a Newtonsoft `JObject` using this code:

```
JObject Json = JObject.Parse(Folders);
```

Below is a simplified version of the JSON I am getting back:

```
{
  "d": {
    "results": [
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "id": "https://client.sharepoint.com/testsubsite/api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='testsubsite/CountryFolders/Germany')"
        },
        "Name": "Germany",
        "itemCount": 3
      },
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "id": "https://client.sharepoint.com/testsubsite/api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='testsubsite/CountryFolders/UK')"
        },
        "Name": "UK",
        "itemCount": 5
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there any way to get this into a `foreach` loop to repeat for the different folders found (in this case 2: "Germany" and UK") or a `for` loop with a count of the results as the limiter.

My C# code is below with "Folders" being the string received from initial query.

```
 JObject Json = JObject.Parse(Folders);
 JArray resultArray = (JArray)Json["results"];
 for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.Count; i++)
 {
     var item = (JObject)resultArray[i];
     //do something with item
 }
```

the `JObject` code is returning a JSON file as expected and `string name = (string)Json["d"]["results"][0]["Name"];` can be used to retrieve the name of the first folder found (Germany).

I've tried to create a `JArray` from "results" but my code gets stuck there. There are no error messages; it just hangs there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code block above, you forgot that `results` is inside `d`.  Since there is no `results` at the root level in the JSON, `resultArray` will be null.  When you try to access the `resultArray.Count` in the loop, you are getting a `NullReferenceException`, but something in your code must be eating it if you are not seeing the error message.

To fix the problem, change this line:

```
JArray resultArray = (JArray)Json["results"];
```

to this:

```
JArray resultArray = (JArray)Json["d"]["results"];
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CcA9Uv